# relation "doctors" doesn't exists

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I am getting this error while running the following code

```
npx sequelize db:seed:all
```

I am trying to populate table called doctors in local postgres database. While running the app, table is getting created successfully, but getting error when trying to seed.

```
Sequelize CLI [Node: 12.18.0, CLI: 6.4.1, ORM: 6.13.0]

(node:44926) ExperimentalWarning: The ESM module loader is experimental.
Loaded configuration file "config/db.config.js".
Using environment "development".
== 20220117094007-add-doctors: migrating =======

ERROR: relation "doctors" does not exist
```

**Heres' how my model looks like:**

```
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt')

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  return sequelize.define(
    'doctors',
    {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      },
      doctorId: {
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        unique: true,
        defaultValue: DataTypes.UUID,
        field: 'doctor_id',
      },
      phoneNumber: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        unique: true,
        field: 'phone_number',
      },
      profilePicUrl: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: true,
        field: 'profile_pic_url',
      },
      firstName: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        field: 'first_name',
        validate: {
          len: {
            args: [2, 5],
            msg: 'Name must be from 2 to 5 characters in length',
          },
        },
      },
      lastName: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        field: 'last_name',
        validate: {
          len: {
            args: [2, 5],
            msg: 'Name must be from 2 to 5 characters in length',
          },
        },
      },
      email: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        isUnique: true,
        allowNull: false,
        field: 'email',
        validate: {
          isEmail: true,
        },
      },
      otpRequestedTime: {
        type: DataTypes.DATE,
        allowNull: true,
        field: 'otp_requested_time',
      },
      dob: {
        type: DataTypes.DATE,
        allowNull: true,
        field: 'dob',
      },
      gender: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: true,
        field: 'gender',
      },
      oneTimePassword: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: true,
        field: 'one_time_password',
      },
      addressPrimary: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: true,
        field: 'address_primary',
      },
      addressSecondary: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: true,
        field: 'address_secondary',
      },
      country: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: true,
        field: 'country',
      },
      state: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: true,
        field: 'state',
      },
      province: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: true,
        field: 'province',
      },
      region: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: true,
        field: 'region',
      },
      division: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: true,
        field: 'division',
      },
      city: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: true,
        field: 'city',
      },
      area: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: true,
        field: 'area',
      },
      timeZone: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: true,
        field: 'time_zone',
      },
      languages: {
        type: DataTypes.JSON,
        allowNull: true,
        field: 'languages',
      },
      password: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        field: 'password',
      },
      isActive: {
        type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
        allowNull: false,
        default: true,
        field: 'is_active',
      },
      isOnline: {
        type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
        allowNull: false,
        default: false,
        field: 'is_online',
      },
      salt: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: true,
        field: 'salt',
      },
      createdAt: {
        type: DataTypes.DATE,
        allowNull: false,
        field: 'created_at',
      },
      updatedAt: {
        type: DataTypes.DATE,
        allowNull: false,
        field: 'updated_at',
      },
    },
    {
      indexes: [
        {
          unique: true,
          fields: ['phone_number', 'email'],
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      hooks: {
        beforeCreate: (doctor) => {
          const salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync()
          doctor.salt = salt
          doctor.password = bcrypt.hashSync(doctor.password, salt)
        },
      },
      instanceMethods: {
        validPassword: function (password) {
          return bcrypt.compareSync(password, this.password)
        },
      },
    },
    {
      freezeTableName: true,
      classMethods: {
        associate() {
          // eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars
          // associations can be defined here
        },
      },
    }
  )
}
```

and this is how my seed file looks like :

```
'use strict'
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt')
module.exports = {
  up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    let doctorArray = [
      {
        doctorId: 'XIDL45DID',
        phoneNumber: '123456789',
        profilePicUrl: 'https://pixabay.com/images/id-2776143/',
        firstName: 'John',
        lastName: 'Doe',
        email: 'john.doe@gmail.com',
        otpRequestedTime: new Date(),
        dob: '02/01/1992',
        gender: 'male',
        oneTimePassword: 'UXTYPR',
        addressPrimary: '123 new address',
        country: 'USA',

        city: 'Los Angeles',

        timeZone: 'America/Los Angeles',
        languages: ['turkish','arabic'],
        isActive: true,
        isOnline: false,
        password: bcrypt.hashSync('test', 8),
        createdAt: new Date(),
        updatedAt: new Date(),
      },
    ]
    return queryInterface.bulkInsert('doctors', doctorArray, {
      returning: true,
    })
  },
  down: async (queryInterface) => {
    await queryInterface.bulkDelete('doctors', null, {})
  },
}
```

These are my project dependencies :

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/register": "^7.16.9",
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "jest": "^27.4.7",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.15",
    "sequelize-cli": "^6.4.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.1",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.1",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^12.0.3",
    "express": "^4.17.2",
    "helmet": "^5.0.1",
    "pg": "^8.7.1",
    "pg-hstore": "^2.3.4",
    "sequelize": "^6.13.0"
  }
```

Stuck on this for a while, any help would  be highly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Are you using [sync](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-basics.html) functions to create the tables?

Comment: @LuizFernandodaSilva Yes, using the following code

`const db = require('./models')

db.sequelize
  .sync({ force: true })
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Drop and re-sync db.')
  })
  .catch((e) => console.log(e)) `

Comment: It's a bad idea to mix `sync` and migrations. Use either `sync` or migrations

Comment: As @Anatoly said, to use migration and sync is a bad idea. Also, sync is worst idea for production projects. I think create tables only though migrations (in a timeline order) may solve the problem.